# Programmatically import and bind SSL cert

Tags: vb.net, iis-7, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5, netsh

I am working on adding SSL cert support to a VB.Net API and I'm having problems getting this to work via code. I can get it to work if I manually import the certificate into IIS and then run my netsh commands. I have a certificate that I created with `mkcert` and its being imported into IIS.

1. Import cert into IIS
2. cmd: `netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443`
3. Start up my API using the https/443 baseurl
4. This works as intended.

When I try to do this via code its not working, I get netsh error `a specified logon session does not exist`. Here is the code that I'm using to import and bind the certificate.

```
' Import the certificate into IIS LocalComputer, this is needed for the ip address bindings.
Dim IIS = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
IIS.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite)
Try
    For Each certificate As X509Certificate2 In x509
        IIS.Add(certificate)
    Next
Finally
    IIS.Close()
End Try

' Bind the SSL Cert to the network address and port.
Dim p As Process = New Process()
Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
Dim cmd As String = " /K " + "netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:" + port.ToString() + " certhash=" + CertificateThumbprint + " appid={myAppId}"
Console.WriteLine(cmd)
pi.Arguments = cmd
pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
p.StartInfo = pi
p.Start()
```

Comment: PInvoke HTTP API and you get what you wanted, https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/v13.0.0.21/Microsoft.Web.Administration/NativeMethods.cs#L317

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to get this working by changing the following:

```
Try
    Dim certificate = New X509Certificate2(CertificatePath, CertificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable Or X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
    IIS.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite)
    IIS.Add(certificate)
Finally
    IIS.Close()
End Try
```